# Select customer from table A then find customer in table B and insert the customer_id into table B

Tags: mysql, database

I am taking old records from excel sheets and moving them into a database.

I have a customers table and an orders table.

The customers table has fields 
customer_id ---primary key ---auto increment
First_Name
Last_Name

The orders table has fields:
customer_id (empty will be a foreign key for customers table)
First_Name (populated)
Last_Name  (populated)

I need to select the customer_id, first_name and last_name row by row from the customers table then find each order in the orders table with the same name the insert the customer_id from the customers table to the orders table.

There are about 5000 orders and 3000 unique customers and I am trying to assign the customer_id to each order.  I can do it manually but it would take a week of Sundays.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your existing table design have issues (like what if two or more customers have same name?), still if you want to update the `customer_id` based on customer name you can try query like following.

```
update o
set o.customer_id =c.customer_id 
from orders o
inner join customers c on c.First_Name =o.First_Name and c.Last_Name=o.Last_Name
```

Comment: Yes that is a small issue I have already come across while doing it manually.   I guess that once I have the data in there I will remove the names from the orders table and just use the customer ID from the customers table to do lookups.   Thanks for the code, will give it a try on a backup copy

Comment: right now the only data I have to link the orders to the customer is the names.  Once I have an ID on each order I can remove the names from the orders table.

Comment: Will give it a go tomorrow, it's after midnight here and I want to be fresh when I run it.  Thanks again

Comment: This is not working for me. 

I also tried this

`update Excel_Orders`
`set Excel_Orders.customer_id =customers.customer_id` 
`from Excel_Orders`
`inner join customers on customers.first_name =Excel_Orders.first_name and customers.last_name=Excel_Orders.last_name`

It complained about both

Comment: query looks fine, it should work unless data is not matching, can you update your question with schema and some sample data. It will help to identify the issue.

Comment: Hi PSK - Not to worry I decided to go ahead and do it manually. Probably would have been a mess doing an import anyway.  Only 2000 records to go ...lol  Thanks for the help :)